# Combining two plots which are in two regions

Tags: plotting

I want to combine two plots which are in two regions. 
For an example, I want to plot following two figures in the same plot.

```
a = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 60}]
b = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 60, 90}]
```

Could anyone please tell me how to do this without using Piecewise function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
a = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 60}, PlotStyle -> Blue];
b = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 60, 90}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[a, b, PlotRange -> All]
```

Is this what you want?

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

> Could anyone please tell me how to do this without using `Piecewise` function?

Cheating:

```
Plot[{ConditionalExpression[Cos[x], x <= 60], ConditionalExpression[Sin[x], x >= 60]},
     {x, 0, 90}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```