# How to combine regions of two 3D plots

Tags: plotting, complex

I need to combine two plots like this [Combining two plots which are in two regions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22172/combining-two-plots-which-are-in-two-regions) but in 3D case. The problem is that I don't know where exactly boundary passes.

I have two complex functions qpC32 and qpC34. And I want to plot only real parts of this functions in such a way that

```
Where Im@qpC32 != 0 do qpC32=0 && Plot[Re@qpC32, {q, 0, 2000}, {m5, 0, 2000}]
Where Im@qpC34 != 0 do qpC34=0 && Plot[Re@qpC34, {q, 0, 2000}, {m5, 0, 2000}]
```

and after that I want to combine two plots:

```
Plot[Re@qpC32+Re@qpC34, {q, 0, 2000}, {m5, 0, 2000}]
```

It is not correct code but it is a general idea what I want to do.

More precisely, I have plots
[image]
[image]

And it is what I want 
[image]

And finally here is my code for my functions and plotting theirs.

```
eqn = j - 
    Sqrt[q^2 + qp^2 - 
      2 q qp Cos[\[Theta]]] - \[Sqrt](qp^2 + 
       1/2 (16 m5^2 + ma^2 + mp^2 - 
          Sqrt[(-(16 m5^2) - ma^2 - mp^2)^2 - 
            4 (ma^2 mp^2 - 16 m5^2 qp^2)])) == 0;
With[{gensol = Solve[eqn , qp]}, 
  Block[{\[Theta] = Pi/12, m = 5.5, M = 300, Nc = 3, c = \!\(\*
TagBox[
InterpretationBox[
RowBox[{"\"\<-4.46874\>\"", "*", 
SuperscriptBox["10", "\"\<4\>\""]}],
-44687.3983417778,
AutoDelete->True],
ScientificForm]\), b = \!\(\*
TagBox[
InterpretationBox[
RowBox[{"\"\<1.61594\>\"", "*", 
SuperscriptBox["10", "\"\<5\>\""]}],
161593.81818181818`,
AutoDelete->True],
ScientificForm]\), k1 = \!\(\*
TagBox[
InterpretationBox[
RowBox[{"\"\<1.6485\>\"", "*", 
SuperscriptBox["10", "\"\<1\>\""]}],
16.485010961790245`,
AutoDelete->True],
ScientificForm]\), k2 = \!\(\*
TagBox[
InterpretationBox[
RowBox[{"\"\<-1.31313\>\"", "*", 
SuperscriptBox["10", "\"\<1\>\""]}],
-13.131344420001051`,
AutoDelete->True],
ScientificForm]\), ma, mp, 
    j},(*subs vals when gensol is evaluated*){j = \[Sqrt](q^2 + 
        1/2 (16 m5^2 + ma^2 + mp^2 + 
           Sqrt[(-(16 m5^2) - ma^2 - mp^2)^2 - 
             4 (ma^2 mp^2 - 16 m5^2 q^2)])), 
    ma = \[Sqrt](-2 (M^2 - 
          2 (3 k1 + k2) (Sqrt[(c + M^2 + 2 m5^2)/(2 (k1 + k2))] + 
             m b/(2 (c + M^2 + 2 m5^2)))^2 - c + 2 m5^2)), 
    mp = Sqrt[
     2 b m (Sqrt[(c + M^2 + 2 m5^2)/(2 (k1 + k2))] + 
        m b/(2 (c + M^2 + 2 m5^2)))^-1]};
   sols = gensol]];
qpC32 = Compile[{{q, _Complex}, {m5, _Complex}}, 
   Evaluate[qp /. sols[[2]]], 
   RuntimeOptions -> "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False] ;
qpC34 = Compile[{{q, _Complex}, {m5, _Complex}}, 
   Evaluate[qp /. sols[[4]]], 
   RuntimeOptions -> "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False] ;  
Plot3D[ Re@qpC34[q, m5], {q, 0, 2000}, {m5, 0, 2000}, 
 PlotRange -> Full]
Plot3D[ Im@qpC34[q, m5], {q, 0, 2000}, {m5, 0, 2000}, 
 PlotRange -> Full]
Plot3D[ Re@qpC32[q, m5], {q, 0, 2000}, {m5, 0, 2000}, 
 PlotRange -> Full]
Plot3D[ Im@qpC32[q, m5], {q, 0, 2000}, {m5, 0, 2000}, 
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use option `RegionFunction` in `Plot3D` to restrict the part that's plotted. First we'll create `RegionFunction`s for each of the plots, and apply them to create the individual plots:

```
rg32 = Function[{q, m5}, Chop[Im[qpC32[q, m5]]] == 0];
rg34 = Function[{q, m5}, Chop[Im[qpC34[q, m5]]] == 0]; 
plt32 = Plot3D[Re@qpC32[q, m5], {q, 0, 2000}, {m5, 0, 2000}, RegionFunction -> rg32];
plt34 = Plot3D[Re@qpC34[q, m5], {q, 0, 2000}, {m5, 0, 2000}, RegionFunction -> rg34];
```

Here I get some warnings about infinities. It's okay; *Mathematica* says it will proceed without compiling the region functions. In this case, it doesn't affect the plots.

Then we show both plots together with `Show[plt34,plt32]`

[image]

I chose `plt34` first in `Show`, because the first plot in `Show` determines the plot range, and `plt34`'s range encompasses that of `plt32`. In general, if you want to make sure you get the full plot range, then you need to specify the plot range for each constituent plot (`plt32` and `plt34`) explicitly with `PlotRange`.